# Drupal Site Index - not crawling through "Blocks"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, sitemap, web-crawler, drupal-blocks

I created a "View"* in Drupal to grab all the content and essentially make a site map, but I realized that it doesn't have an option to grab content from the Blocks I have created. Does anyone have an idea if I can even do that?

If not, should I essentially make each block a page so that it can crawl through the pages? I worry that this will end up becoming unmanageable in the end... What are some other options/work arounds? My end goal is to make a site map - maybe I am making this too complicated?

*To make my view I did: 
Administration->Structure->Views->Add. Then I made it a page, called it "site-index", and made it "**show Content of type All**" (with tagged field empty). Then I chose "Content: Title" for my Fields and my Filter Criteria is set as: "Content: Published (Yes):" - That way, it will grab the titles of my web pages.

Thanks, and please reply if further clarification is needed!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I'm wrong but I think there might be a bit of confusion over terminology here. In the context of a view `Content` means nodes, not all HTML content on the site.  Your view will return a list of all published nodes, which are essentially the pages on your site.

On a normal sitemap (if there is such a thing) you would only link to full pages, not to parts of pages like a block, they are essentially used to provide a hierarchical overview of your site to aid navigation for users and, probably more importantly these days, search engines (you can submit an XML sitemap to the major search engines instead of this but that's really for another question).

Rather than doing this yourself I'd actually recommend you download and install the [Sitemap module](http://drupal.org/project/site_map) which will do all of the work for you, as well as arranging the content in their respective hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks Clive! I think I was confused a bit on terminology. I am new to Drupal, heh. Thanks so much, I will give the module a try!